# Can Mesmerizing Glare enable the use of Suggestion?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, bard

Is there anything stopping someone from using the Mesmerizing glare spell to allow them to use the bard's suggestion class feature on someone?

Answer (score 1):

Going by RAW, yes, so long as the bard is the caster of *Mesmerizing Glare* he could then use *Suggestion* on them.

> **Suggestion (Sp)**: A bard of 6th level or higher with 9 or more ranks
>   in a *Perform* skill can make a *suggestion* (as the spell) to a creature
>   that **he** has already *fascinated* (see above).

Emphasis mine. Using up one of the Bard's few level 2 spell slots to do something he or she could do with one of their music uses isn't particularly powerful, so I can't see any issue with this from a RAI standpoint either. Chances are the DC is higher from the bardsong too.

Answer (score 1):

## A creature must be [fascinated](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_fascinated&alpha=F) by the bard's [bardic music](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html#bardic-music) [*fascinate*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html#fascinate) for the bard to use on that creature the [bardic music](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html#bardic-music) [*suggestion*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html#suggestion)

The bard's bardic music spell-like ability [*suggestion*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html#suggestion) says

> **A bard** of 6th level or higher with 9 or more ranks in a Perform skill **can make a *suggestion*** (as the spell) **to a creature that he has already fascinated (see above)**. Using this ability does not break the bard’s concentration on the fascinate effect, nor does it allow a second saving throw against the fascinate effect.
>
> Making a suggestion doesn’t count against a bard’s daily limit on bardic music performances. A Will saving throw (DC 10 + 1/2 bard’s level + bard’s Cha modifier) negates the effect. This ability affects only a single creature (but see mass suggestion, below). Suggestion is an enchantment (compulsion), mind-affecting, language dependent ability.

(Emphasis mine.) That telltale *(see above)* in the description of the [bard](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html)'s spell-like ability [*suggestion*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/bard.html#suggestion) indicates that the bard *must* use first the bardic music spell-like ability *fascinate* to render a foe [fascinated](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_fascinated&alpha=F) if the bard later wants to use the bardic music spell-like ability *suggestion* on that foe. (Literally above *suggestion* in the bardic music description appears *fascinate*.) The bard *can't* cast a spell or employ another effect that *just so happens* to render the foe fascinated—like the 2nd-level bard spell *mesmerizing glare* [ench] (*SpC* 140) or the [*pipes of pain*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsWI.html#pipes-of-pain) (*DMG* 264) (12,000 gp; 0 lbs.)—*then* use the spell-like ability *suggestion* for free.

But after having used bardic music's *fascinate* to fascinate a foe—likely because the bard's spell-like ability *fascinate* has limited uses, limited range, limited targeting, and is impossible if "nearby combat or other dangers" (*PH* 29) exist—, the bard's subsequent *suggestion* is *nearly* free. That is, so long as the creature remains fascinated by the bard's bardic music *fascinate*, the bard can take a standard action to make a bardic music *suggestion*. (The inability of the typical bard to use in combat bardic music *fascinate*—therefore, also, *suggestion*—may explain why the bard was considering as a workaround the *mesmerizing glare* spell!)

### "What if I *want* bardic music's *suggestion* to have a broader mandate?"

It's probably not unbalancing to make a house rule that allows the bard to use bardic music's spell-like ability *suggestion* against *any* creature the bard successfully fascinates, no matter the source so long as the bard can be said to have somehow generated the condition. The condition [fascinate](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_fascinated&alpha=F) is easily broken, making the *suggestion* still takes a standard action, and the *suggestion*'s saving throw DC—unlike many spell-like abilities—*is* relatively low. However, [*suggestion*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsS.html#suggestion) remains a 3rd-level effect and those probably shouldn't be *totally* free, so this DM would include as part of such a house rule that each spell-like *suggestion* attempt made under such conditions expends 1 of the bard's daily uses of bardic music.

Comment: I'd argue that at level 6 you have 6 song uses, 2+Cha mod lvl 2 spells uses, your DC for your songs is likely 19+Cha mod or more and your DC for a level 2 spell is 12+Cha mod. Plus the range of your song is 90ft, for the spell it's 40ft at level 6. The spell is worse in all aspects except it doesn't use one of the Bard's songs per day, which for me is an acceptable tradeoff. The parentheses, to me, are just giving an example, if you assume they are excluding all other sources of **fascinate**, the sentence reads very oddly. +1 for a good answer either way.

Comment: @gaynorvader The spell *mesmerizing glare* is actually *better* in every way than bardic music *fascinate* because the spell can be used in combat while the typical as-written bard can't use in combat at all *suggestion* because in combat he can't use *fascinate*! I'd argue that divorcing bard music *suggestion* from bard music *fascinate* doesn't make sense because then the *suggestion* interacts with bardic music *only* because of the required Perform ranks, unlike all the other bardic music effects (save, of course, *mass suggestion*).

Comment: A very good point, one I had overlooked. The spell is worse in every way except that it can be used in combat, which is a pretty significant exception. I still feel thematically it makes no sense that suggestion wouldn't work on any creature fascinated by the bard. Perhaps only allowing it to be used with the same caveats as fascinate? Hm.

Comment: @gaynorvader As an aside, while the question asks about *mesmerizing glare*—a fairly obscure spell, to be honest—the 1st-level bard spell *hypnotism* and the 3rd-level bard spell *hypnotic pattern* also leave foes fascinated. So it's not as though a DM that's using your answer and that's unhappy with the bard getting free *suggestions* for the price of a 2nd-level spell can simply ban the *glare* spell and think *Now that pesky bard can't use* suggestion *in combat anymore!* A raft of changes potentially ripple from reading that *(see above)* in *suggestion* as unrelated to bardic music.

Comment: Agreed, however, it is how I read that rule and the only way it makes sense thematically in my head. If the writers had named the bardsong "**fascinating performance**" or referred to it as "the bardic power, fascinate" in the description, I'd agree with you, but the books are full of these kinds of strange ambiguities. If a DM decided a bard using **suggestion** in combat was too strong he could rule that it only works sans distractions, like the bardsong. For me, the drastically reduced DC of the saving throw on the spells make up for it (basically a 2 round cast time for charm person).

Comment: We're reaching the comment limit here, but I would like to point out that the bard's *fascinate* and *suggestion* are both parts of a section in the bard description entitled Bardic Music. It's not as though the special ability *suggestion* exists in isolation as a separate special ability the bard possesses. Instead, *suggestion* is part of a *cascade* of abilities related to bardic music, and one such ability is *fascinate* that is, actually and for reals, *above*  another ability named *suggestion* on the printed page! I don't think the ambiguity is really *that* vast.

Answer (score 0):

The ability and the condition have the same name so it can be counfonding but it is clear that suggestion works only for the class feature.

> Suggestion (Sp): A bard of 6th level or higher with 9 or more ranks in a Perform skill can make a suggestion (as the spell) to a
>   creature that he has already fascinated (see above). Using this
>   ability does not break the bard’s concentration on the fascinate
>   effect, nor does it allow a second saving throw against the fascinate
>   effect.

Indeed:

1) it say '...fascinated (**see above**)', and above there isn't the condition but the bardic music ability

2) the reference to concentration and to the second saving throw. There can be many ways to make fascinated (condition) and not all of them need concentration or have ST. If it work for all of them it should say something like '**eventually** concentration'

3) also, so works for the other bardic music abilities